# Linux Permissions via group and user IDs

Tags: permissions, groups

This is such an elementary question, and I can't believe I've been using Unix (Linux and Mac) for over 5 years without knowing this!

The root user has group id 0 and user id 0.  Hence lower group ids have more permission.  The question is, if I want to create an administrator group, where all members have the same rights as the root group, is that a safe practice?  And do I create than by setting to the group id to 0?  All this time I've been going along with *sudo* but that's because I've been the only user on my machine or vps.

Also, when a group id is say 10 or 100, can it perform any operation on any file that belongs to a group that say has an id of 1000?  Is that how that's supposed to work?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood something. You don't get "more" permissions by having a lower UID or GID, unless it happens to be 0 (root).

Comment: Look into the principal of the `wheel` group and read up on `visudo` and `sudoers`

Comment: You are confusing Unix/Linux operations with that old and venerable VAX system where userid numbering did determine native permissions. Yes, there were other ways to assign privs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each group in UNIX systems has its own unique ID. This is the primary identifier, the name is just some kind of alias.

> In Unix systems, every user must be a member of at least one group,
>   which is identified by the numeric GID of the user's entry in
>   /etc/passwd. (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier))

The numerical value of the group ID is not in any way connected to the permissions of that group. Group ID 0 is a special case, as it's always the superuser group.

*The question is, if I want to create an administrator group, where all members have the same rights as the root group, is that a safe practice? And do I create than by setting to the group id to 0?*

Per sé this is **not** a safe practice. `sudo` has been invented for a reason. Modern distributions have a *sudo* or *admin* group. Add the user you want to use for admin tasks to this group.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Ubuntu (for the last couple of years).  What I had been doing is adding my user to the sudoers groups and just running commands with sudo.  I thought there might be a better practice.  When I edit /etc/sudoers can I specify a group instead of a user?